# Chinese symbol on English keyboard layout on iPad Air / iOS 13

Tags: ipad, keyboard, ipados

Anyone know what this Chinese symbol is on the keyboard next to the return key?

There are no Chinese layouts enabled and the OS is in English.
Seeing this on an iPad Air 3rd gen / iOS 13.3.1

Pressing it doesn't seem to do anything, and translating the symbol with google translate shows it as ~ full width / half screen

[image]

Comment: Just an interesting fact, I have an iPad Air 3 running iPadOS and my return key also doesn’t have the arrow symbol like it does in your picture. It just says “return.” Do the Chinese characters only appear inside a specific app? If so, perhaps the app you are using modified the keyboard slightly.

Comment: Does this character appear in other apps’ keyboards as well? Also - what happens when you press it?